# How do I use or in Python 3.6

Tags: python, if-statement

So I'm making a calculator in python 3.6, but there is an error message and my code is not working.

```
if(op == "+"):
    print(add(num1, num2))
if(op == "-"):
    print(sub(num1, num2))
if(op == "*"):
    print(mul(num1, num2))
if(op == "/"):
    print(dev(num1, num2))
if(op == "stop"):
    rng = "f"
elif(op != "+", or "-", or "*", or "/", or "stop"):
    print("Please enter a valid operation!")
```

When I run the code, it gives me an error saying invalid syntax and highlights  the "or" part in the string. [Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfVSF.png). How do I fix this?

Comment: I'd recommend looking up an example of `or` before using it, the commas are invalid. Remove them, after that you will won't get respected results because it separates conditions (ex: `"-"` by itself is always true). But you don't need those conditions, just make the other items into `elseif` and change your `elseif` to `else`.

Comment: Why not say `op not in {'+', '-', '*', '/'', 'stop'}` ?

Comment: Or, possibly, `else` might suffice instead of `elif`.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis You would also want to add `elif` to the pervious conditions as well in that case.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Agreed. I think OP needs to reconsider logic before worrying about syntax errors. Too often the message is "what's wrong?" instead of "how can this be done better?"

Comment: @RobotechGamer, have you considered putting your functions in a dictionary (see my answer)? This is cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: Python does not support the [Oxford comma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question it's a syntax error because `or` does not expect a comma. Remove those and it won't produce an error:

```
...
elif(op != "+" or "-" or "*" or "/" or "stop"):
    print("Please enter a valid operation!")
```

The problem with this is `or` is separates and applies a logical or to each condition separately as in: `op != "+"`, `"-"`, `"*"`, and so on. A string value by itself that isn't empty will always be true, as such your condition will be true always. So you will want to add on: `op != "-"`, `op != "*"`, and so on. Even with that adding those there is still a logical error as `op` can only be a single value at a time. As such it will still always evaluate to `true`, so you likely mean to use `and` instead.

But that entire condition is really not necessary. Simply use `elif` on the pervious conditions:

```
if(op == "+"):
    print(add(num1, num2))
elif(op == "-"):
    print(sub(num1, num2))
elif(op == "*"):
    print(mul(num1, num2))
elif(op == "/"):
    print(dev(num1, num2))
elif(op == "stop"):
    rng = "f"
else:
    print("Please enter a valid operation!")
```

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks Missed the `:` in `else:`. Fixed.

Comment: I would've just made an edit but single-character edits aren't allowed ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'or' like this:

```
if 5 == 5 or 4 == 4:
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print("Incorrect!")
```

So, no commas. Also take out the brackets in the 'if' statement.

But in your case, use or like this:

```
if userInput != 5 or userInput != 6 or userInput != 7:
    print("Do Something ...")
else:
    print("Do Something ...")
```

I know, you have to write the something over and over again.

Also by the way, change your `or`s to `and`s because then your code won't run as expected.

Comment: Python code does not compile, it's interpretive. Having `or`'s will not prevent it from running, but may not give the boolean the OP is looking for depending on what they are trying to do.

Comment: When I mean compile, I mean running the code. Sorry, let me fix it.

Answer (score 1):

```
elif(op != "+" and op != "-" and op != "*" and op != "/" and op != "stop"):
    print("Please enter a valid operation!")
```

This is the correct syntax. Turns out you can't use 'op!=' once followed by several or(s) in order to check all the conditions.

Comment: `op != "+" or op != "-"` will always be true. Please check your logic before posting answers.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks Technically the OP is only asking to fix their syntax errors, rather than their logical errors. As such this answer is entirely valid.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Giving the least possible help that is technically correct seems... not very helpful. It's very clear what is meant to happen here and it's equally clear that this answer won't accomplish that.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks Make no mistake I'm not considering this a good answer by any means. Just that it answers the question.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes Thanks mate, It was my first answer so I'll take care of it in future thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks I was just trying to answer point-to-point, clearly, he's a beginner(so am I) and he wanted help for fixing that error, I tried to help him with that by answering him what the correct syntax is.

Comment: @NamanSingh I understand! And I'm trying to help you give better answers. Your answer would stop the syntax error but leave another problem, that the code will print the request for a valid operation every time the user has entered anything besides "stop". Especially as a beginner it's important that you make sure your suggestions work well.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks Alright, thanks, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should include "and !=" (which means not equal to) instead of ", or" 
This code will do the job:

```
if(op == "+"):
    print(add(num1, num2))
if(op == "-"):
    print(sub(num1, num2))
if(op == "*"):
    print(mul(num1, num2))
if(op == "/"):
    print(dev(num1, num2))
if(op == "stop"):
    rng = "f"
elif(op != "+" and op != "-" and op != "*" and op != "/" and op !="stop"):
    print("Please enter a valid operation!")
```

Answer (score 0):

This, in my opinion, is a more pythonic solution.

```
op_map = {'+': add, '-': sub, '*': mul, '/': dev}

if op in op_map:
    print(op_map[op](num1, num2))

elif op == 'stop':
    rng = 'f'

else:
    print('Please enter a valid operation!')
```